# Xinit/zsh: jobs control

Tags: zsh, xinit

In `.xinitrc`, there'll have multiple lines with `&` to put some commands in background, I'd like to control if a command is completed or not before process to next command.

I use `zsh` in `.xinitrc` file, not `sh`.

How we can achive this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `&` puts a job in the background and causes execution to continue to the next line. If you want to wait to see whether a command is completed or not, remove the `&`.

**From:**

```
command1 &
command2 &
command3
```

**To:**

```
command1
command2
command3
```

If you want subsequent commands to execute only if the previous command(s) were successful, then chain them together with `&&`:

```
command1 &&
command2 &&
command3
```